# Take user input and use it as Process

Tags: c#, process, openfiledialog

So basically, I have a OpenFileDialog where the user will select a location.
I made it so it would display the directory in a textbox.
But what  I want is have another button which would take that directory and start it by using `ProcessStartInfo`.

OpenFileDialog, showing it in TextBox:

```
    public void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.Title = "Open Arma 3";
        ofd.Filter = "EXE file|*.exe";

        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            textBox1.Text = ofd.FileName;
        }
    }
```

Process:

```
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.FileName = //RESULT OPENFILEDIALOG SHOULD BE HERE 
        startInfo.Arguments = @"-window -useBE -mod=e:\Aaron\Addons\@CBA_A3";
        Process.Start(startInfo);
    }
```

Comment: Please provide more information? What is your question/ problem? Or do you only want to know how to fill the startInfo.FileName? You can just use the text of textBox1: startInfo.FileName = textBox1.Text.

Comment: I just updated it. ;)

Comment: Read the second part of the first comment :)

Comment: Already figured it out with startInfo.FileName = textBox1.Text.
I tried out alot of stuff. Weird enough I didn't seem to try that. Thanks!

Comment: Anyway, another quick question. In another part of the program I do the same. But after the direction the user choses then there has to be another part of direction.

For example the user would select;
C\User\Name\Afolder
I would still have to put other folders behind that like;
C\User\Name\Afolder\Anotherfolder

How would I do that?

Comment: Please modify your first post and provide more information. What do you mean by 'after the direction the user choses then there has to be another part of direction'?

Comment: I'll try to fix it myself. If I can't figure it out I'll make another question and post question link here. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm glad I could help and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already save the result of the OpenFileDialog in textBox1, you can easily access it in the button3_Click event handler.

To fill the startInfo.FileName:

*I added an extra IsNullOrWhiteSpace check, so the application doesn't start another process if the textBox1.Text is empty.

```
if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox1.Text)
{
      ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
      startInfo.FileName = textBox1.Text
      startInfo.Arguments = @"-window -useBE -mod=e:\Aaron\Addons\@CBA_A3";
      Process.Start(startInfo);
}
```